# Print member's name

Tags: php, select, printing

I try to print the username in members panel.
That means when the member login, I will print to him, for example, "Welcome MEMBER'S NAME".

The problem is, when I use this script to print the member name, it print to me all members from my database:

```
<?php
    $id = @$_GET['id'];
    $name = @$_GET['name'];
    $select = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id='$id'";
    $run = mysqli_query($connect,$select);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
        echo $row['name']; 
    }
?>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: please show us the value of `$id`?

Comment: try `$select = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id=".$id." ";`

Comment: If you are only expecting 1 value, why are you doing a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You should sanitize the `$_GET` as `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);` and instead of looping through the record resource you can use

```
   $select = "SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id='$id'";
    $run = mysqli_query($connect,$select);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run);
    echo $row['name'];
```